# Is it possible to isolate $ac/bc/bd$ from the equation $x=ab+cd$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Here is a tricky algebra problem I couldn't figure out, I am wondering if anyone else could, or if it's even possible. $$ x = ab + cd$$ The goal is to completely isolate ac (or $bc$ or $bd$ or $ad$ it doesn't matter)

Everything I try results in $a$ or $c$ being stuck somewhere on both sides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can't be done.

More precisely, from the equation
$$
x=ab+cd
$$
it's not possible to solve for $ac$ in terms of $b,d,x$.

For example, suppose $b=d=x=1$.

Then the equation reduces to
$$
a+c=1
$$
so for any choice of $a$ we get
$$
ac=a(1-a)
$$
which varies with $a$.

Comment: You're right +1

Answer (score 0):

Solve for a. Then start over and solve for c. Then arrange a new equation such that ac = (everything except a from first rearrangement)(everything except c from second rearrangement) and simplify.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).